# CSS Custom Font not showing on second line

Tags: css, fonts

I have a custom font imported to this page using CSS: http://roundup.amebc.ca/

When Show Hotel List is clicked in Chrome, the custom font is ignored on the second line even though it is under the same heading and styling as the line above it (ex: Downtown and Harbourfront). I haven't been able to find anything that talks about this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question.  [You cannot just a link to your site (please also read this link)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.hotel-list p {
    font-family: 'Calibre-SemiBold';
}
```

Edit: This solution worked because if you view source or inspect one of the items in question on your page, you will see that they are all in fact wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Your `<p>` tag had not yet been styled to show the font you wanted so it was falling back to the font that was set on the `<body>`.

Hope this makes sense - see image below

[image: paragraph tags inside your <code>.hotel</code> element]

Comment: That worked great, thanks a lot. Can I ask why that helped, considering they aren't even in a P tag?